# Android M : VoIP, JAINSIP, SipStack; inconsistent SipProvider Exception when creating a listening point with tls enabled

Tags: android, sip, voip, android-6.0-marshmallow, jain-sip

**UPDATE 5**:
*Gist of what is happening*: The tcp listening point is created under stack initialisation. For that, we cannot use an existing object, in our case.
So what i do is check if the `mTcp` is not `null`, and if it is then the listening point is deleted and function proceeds with stack init but the `!=null` is always skipped and then the consequent exception...
Note: Using a random port number every time does not work for creating the listening point does not work in Android whereas the same works for iOS.

**UPDATE 4**:
Started facing this in Xiaomi Mi 4:
 SipProvider Exception is android.javax.sip.InvalidArgumentException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

**UPDATE 3**:
There seems to be a pattern for exceptions to alternate. But the immediate 2nd attempt is successful in that too;
1. 1st time `createListeningPoint()` is called -> Exception 2 or 1
2. 2nd attempt after that -> success
3. After that, when *1.* happens -> Exception 1 or 2
4. 2nd attempt -> success . . .

**UPDATE 2**:

Exceptions 1 and 2 seem to reproduce without any pattern but 2nd attempt is successful after *Exception 2*, where as when it is *Exception 1*- it sticks for a while and repeatedly gives the same exception.

---

**UPDATE 1**:

***1.*** The SipProvider exception occurs only ONCE after the sip stack is destroyed. The 2nd attempt to register/initialise stack or create the listening point is always successful.

***2.*** Another Nexus 5 device running on Android M does not have the same behaviour; everything works as expected.

***3.*** Now the same issue occurs in Motorola Nexus 6 Android M also. Not sure if it is due to an update of one of the apps or the o.s. No success on 2nd attempts either in this.

---

The following behaviour has been *inconsistent*, *random*. I do not have the precise steps to reproduce it.
This happens
**only on Nexus 5** after the **Android M** ota update,

I am using JainSip in a ***VoIP app.

Scenario: when the **createListeningPoint** is called with **tls enabled**;

```
listeningPoint = mSipStack.createListeningPoint("stringIp",intPortNumber,
                    "stringTls");
```

These are the exceptions that occur randomly

***Exception 1***:

```
SipProvider Exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   
cipherSuite TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA is not supported.
```

***Exception 2***:

```
SipProvider Exception is android.javax.sip.InvalidArgumentException:  
bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

For Sip Stack jar(s), i am using:
[Maven android jain sip](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.sip/android-jain-sip-ri/1.2.247) and have tried [jenkins jsip](https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/)

***Note these:***
**1.** The same code works as expected in other devices and o.s. versions below/before Android 6.0 (API 23).
**2.** Code worked as expected in Android M preview sdk loaded into Motorola Nexus 6
**3.** Have not tested it on multiple devices with Android M yet, not even multiple Nexus 5 (s). I'l post an update when i do that.

I searched for the issue, could not find much, tried using [setEnabledCipherSuites](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.net.ssl/SSLSocketsetEnabledCipherSuitesStringarg0.htm) for Exception 1 -not sure how to implement it- and ensuring that listening point is null/destroyed when the stack deregisters, for Exception 2.

The question is has anybody experienced the same or know what is happening, how to solve that (?)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by commenting out 

"TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",

"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"

in the 'cipherSuites' String[] in SipStackImpl.java

The two are no longer supported from Android 6

Comment: You can just create two instances of the cipher suites array, one for pre M and one for M+. The one for M+ should not contain anonymous cipher suites (with _anon_ in them), as they are no longer supported.